# Get the Query Executed in Laravel 3/4

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I retrieve the raw executed SQL query in Laravel 3/4 using Laravel Query Builder or Eloquent ORM?

For example, something like this:

```
DB::table('users')->where_status(1)->get();
```

Or:

```
(posts (id, user_id, ...))

User::find(1)->posts->get();
```

Otherwise, at the very least how can I save all queries executed to laravel.log?

Comment: what about in laravel 5?

Comment: @Adamnick here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr

Answer (score 320, accepted):

## Laravel 4+

> **Note for Laravel 5 users:** You'll need to call `DB::enableQueryLog()` before executing the query. Either just above the line that runs the query or inside a middleware.

In Laravel 4 and later, you have to call `DB::getQueryLog()` to get all ran queries.

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

Or you can download a profiler package. I'd recommend [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), which is pretty neat. You can read for instructions on how to install in their [repository](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

---

## Laravel 3

In Laravel 3, you can get the last executed query from an `Eloquent` model calling the static method `last_query` on the `DB` class.

```
DB::last_query();
```

This, however, requires that you enable the `profiler` option in `application/config/database.php`. Alternatively you could, as @dualed mentioned, enable the `profiler` option, in `application/config/application.php` or call `DB::profile()` to get all queries ran in the current request and their execution time.

Comment: Your code for Laravel 4 doesn't work. I get this `ErrorException`: Warning: `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class `Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection` does not have a method `getQueryList`.

Comment: My bad, the correct method is `getQueryLog`. Fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: Strange... I get last_query() is not defined on the Query object error. I am just calling on an uninstantiated Eloquent model.

Comment: For Laravel 3 it's actually DB::last_query(); You also need to set 'profile' to true in your application/config/database.php

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for an Eloquent Model on L4. When I execute Model::find($id) and perform DB::getQueryLog() return blank array(). Any idea how to get the queries for an Eloquent Model?

Comment: dd(end(DB::getQueryLog()));

Comment: L4 oneliner: `$q=\DB::getQueryLog();dd(end($q));`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski isn't that just a longer version of MECU's answer? I really don't see the point.

Comment: @rmobis MECU answer dont work in my L4 project - this is why i put my version. May be MECU answer work on L3 or L5 (?)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski he just forgot the `\ ` before `DB::getQueryLog()`. Apart from that, the two are identical.

Comment: @rmobis - no i have different error - try yourself. there was a problem with end(here_must_be_veraiable_not_function)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Oh, you're right. It's because `end`'s argument is passed by reference so it has to be an actual variable. Good catch.

Comment: @rmobis ok so please give point to my comment with oneliner to be better visible to other people :)

Comment: in Laravel 3 long queries are truncated, any idea?

Comment: I am getting to be a regular visitor of this page.

Answer (score 31):

You can enable the "*Profiler*" in Laravel 3 by setting

```
'profiler' => true,
```

In your `application/config/application.php` and `application/config/database.php`

This enables a bar at the bottom of each page. One of its features is listing the executed queries and how long each one took.

[image]

Comment: Note that in Laravel 4, the Profiler is not included, you have to install it by yourself (e.g. using composer). See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4).

Comment: It's discussed in the [first answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14536215/291557).

Answer (score 26):

For Eloquent you can just do:

```
$result->getQuery()->toSql();
```

But you need to remove the "->get()" part from your query.

Answer (score 19):

I would recommend using the Chrome extension [Clockwork](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp) with the Laravel package https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork. It's easy to install and use.

> Clockwork is a Chrome extension for PHP development, extending
>   Developer Tools with a new panel providing all kinds of information
>   useful for debugging and profiling your PHP scripts, including
>   information on request, headers, GET and POST data, cookies, session
>   data, database queries, routes, visualisation of application runtime
>   and more. Clockwork includes out of the box support for Laravel 4 and
>   Slim 2 based applications, you can add support for any other or custom
>   framework via an extensible API.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Since the profiler is not yet out in **Laravel 4**, I've created this helper function to see the SQL being generated:

```
    public static function q($all = true) 
    {
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();

        if($all == false) {
            $last_query = end($queries);
            return $last_query;
        }

        return $queries;
    }
```

**NOTE**: Set the *$all* flag to *false* if you only want the last SQL query.

I keep this sort of functions in a class called DBH.php (short for Database Helper) so I can call it from anywhere like this:

```
dd(DBH::q());
```

Here is the output I get: 
[image]

In case you are wondering, I use Kint for the dd() formatting.
http://raveren.github.io/kint/

Comment: `if($all == false)`? Why not simply `if(!$all)`

Answer (score 14):

For Laraver 4 it's

```
DB::getQueryLog()
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is a quick Javascript snippet you can throw onto your master page template.
As long as it's included, all queries will be output to your browser's Javascript Console.
It prints them in an easily readable list, making it simple to browse around your site and see what queries are executing on each page.

When you're done debugging, just remove it from your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var queries = {{ json_encode(DB::getQueryLog()) }};
    console.log('/****************************** Database Queries ******************************/');
    console.log(' ');
    queries.forEach(function(query) {
        console.log('   ' + query.time + ' | ' + query.query + ' | ' + query.bindings[0]);
    });
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('/****************************** End Queries ***********************************/');
</script>
```

Comment: I think you would need "" around the {{ json_encode... }} part

Comment: @mydoglixu Since `DB::getQueryLog()` returns an array, there's no need to surround it with "". `json_encode` will translate it accordingly.

Comment: @mobis - I meant that you need the "" outside the {{ ... }} so that javascript doesn't throw an error. like this: var queries = "json output";

Comment: @mydoglixu You don't, because a JSON array (or object) is valid JavaScript. It would break if you did.

Comment: @mobis - oh yeah, duh

Answer (score 11):

## Laravel 5

Note that this is the *procedural* approach, which I use for quick debugging

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();

    // Run your queries
    // ...

    // Then to retrieve everything since you enabled the logging:
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    foreach($queries as $i=>$query)
    {
        Log::debug("Query $i: " . json_encode($query));
    }
```

in your header, use:

```
     use DB;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

The output will look something like this (default log file is **laravel.log**):

> [2015-09-25 12:33:29] testing.DEBUG: Query 0: {"query":"select * from
>   'users' where ('user_id' = ?)","bindings":["9"],"time":0.23}

***I know this question specified Laravel 3/4 but this page comes up when searching for a general answer. Newbies to Laravel may not know there is a difference between versions. Since I never see `DD::enableQueryLog()` mentioned in any of the answers I normally find, it *may* be specific to Laravel 5 - perhaps someone can comment on that.

Answer (score 7):

You can also listen for query events using this:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

See the information from the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/database#running-queries) under *Listening For Query Events*

Answer (score 6):

Using the query log doesnt give you the actual RAW query being executed, especially if there are bound values.
This is the best approach to get the raw sql:

```
DB::table('tablename')->toSql();
```

or more involved:

```
$query = Article::whereIn('author_id', [1,2,3])->orderBy('published', 'desc')->toSql();
dd($query);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Laravel 5 you need to insert this before query or on middleware :

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Answer (score 4):

Or as alternative to laravel 3 profiler you can use:

https://github.com/paulboco/profiler
or
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 3):

in Laravel 4 you can actually use an Event Listener for database queries.

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql, $bindings)
{
    foreach ($bindings as $val) {
        $sql = preg_replace('/\?/', "'{$val}'", $sql, 1);
    }

    Log::info($sql);
});
```

Place this snippet anywhere, e.g. in `start/global.php`. It'll write the queries to the info log (`storage/log/laravel.log`).

Answer (score 3):

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql, $param)
{
    \Log::info($sql . ", with[" . join(',', $param) ."]<br>\n");
});
```

put it in global.php it will log your sql query.

Answer (score 2):

The Loic Sharma SQL profiler does support Laravel 4, I just installed it. The instructions [are listed here](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler). The steps are the following:

1. Add         `"loic-sharma/profiler": "1.1.*"` in the require section
   in composer.json
2. Perform self-update => `php composer.phar self-update` in the console.
3. Perform composer update => `php composer.phar update loic-sharma/profiler` in the console as well
   `
4. Add `'Profiler\ProfilerServiceProvider',` in the provider array in
   app.php
5. Add `'Profiler'        => 'Profiler\Facades\Profiler',` in the
   aliasses array in app.php as well
6. Run `php artisan config:publish loic-sharma/profiler` in the console

Answer (score 2):

**Last query print**

```
$queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);

// Add binding to query
foreach ($last_query['bindings'] as $val) {
        $last_query['query'] = preg_replace('/\?/', "'{$val}'", $last_query['query'], 1);
}
dd($last_query);
```

Answer (score 1):

## L4 one-liner

(which write query):

`$q=\DB::getQueryLog();dd(end($q));`

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel 3

Another way to do this is:

```
#config/database.php

'profiler' => true
```

For all Queries result:

```
print_r(DB::profiler());
```

For last Result:

```
print_r(DB::last_query());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last executed query in laravel,We will use `DB::getQueryLog()` function of laravel it return all executed queries. To get last query we will use `end()` function which return last executed query.

```
$student = DB::table('student')->get();
$query = DB::getQueryLog();
$lastQuery = end($query);
print_r($lastQuery);
```

I have taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/how-to-get-the-last-executed-query-in-laravel.php.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to contribute any new knowledge to what the accepted answer by Raphael_ already covers.

Answer (score 0):

There is very easy way to do it, from your laravel query just rename any column name, it will show you an error with your query.. :)

Comment: Quick hacky way. Not to useful in production, but in development mode it's fine in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

**In Laravel 8.x** you can listen to the event by registering your query listener in a **service provider** as documented in [laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#listening-for-query-events) website.

```php
//header
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

public function boot()
{
   
  DB::listen(function ($query) {            
   Log::debug("SQL : " . $query->sql);
  });

}
```

You can then see all the queries in the *laravel.log* file inside `storage\logs\laravel.log`