# Laravel 4 MySQL query to array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 and I need to take entries from my database, put them into an array and use them in a foreach loop in my view.

I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting anything from the database.

I'm trying to edit this page of a Laravel bundle to get products from the database, rather than statically.

This is my query from my Model

```
return $products = \DB::select('select * from products', array('sku', 'name'));
```

Controller...

```
public function getIndex()
{
    // Get the products.
    //
    $products = Products::all();

    // Show the page.
    //
    return View::make('shpcart::home')->with('products', $products);
}
```

This is my view

```
<pre>
<?php
   print_r($products);
?>
</pre>
```

This is the result

Array
(
)

This works to insert into the database:

```
DB::insert('insert into products (sku, name) values (?, ?)', array('WS004', 'Test'));
```

This...

```
$products = DB::table('products')->get();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
echo $product->sku;
}
```

returns the error

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

You can see it here...

http://wilsonswan.co.uk/collection

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are not passing the $products variable to the view

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to include the controller. I have edited above.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a question on github: https://github.com/rktaiwala/Shpcart/issues

Comment: what your Product model looks like

Answer (score 0):

You should not return $products as such.

You should perhaps do something like:

```
public function index()
{
$products = Products::where('sku', '=', 'name')->get();

return View::make('view', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error 'Class 'Products' not found'. I guess this is because I have not set it up.

I'm trying to customise this page of a bundle to get products from the database, rather than statically.

https://github.com/rktaiwala/Shpcart/blob/master/src/Models/Products.php

Comment: I am not familiar with that package, but you will have to check the SQL query passed to the database to identify what exactly is happening. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14536215/385402

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $db = DB::table('products as p')
               ->where('p.sku', '=', 'WS004');

    $products = $db->get();

    return View::make('shpcart::home')
              ->with('products', $products);
}
```