# Laravel 4 view sql query

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

When working on Laravel, we do query like this:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
```

How can I view the generated sql query? This is something very important for debugging during the development.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4/14536215#14536215), you should be able to use this to get the last executed query :

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); // gets a log of all executed queries
$last_query = end($queries); // gets the last one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this snippet:

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql)
{
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

It will output all queries being executed in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer as other people have answered this but take a look at this composer package, it is very helpful and displays all of your queries and more.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar