# How do i get the result query from a Laravel ORM object?

Tags: php, laravel

i am doing a lot of laravel ORM objects and querying to the database from ORM and from query Builder also.
What i would like to know is if there is any function to the ORM object or Query BUilder object that could return back to me the actual query string.

like

ORM_object->getResultQuery()

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4

Comment: Thank you! :) actually i found it also after :/