# Issue with eager loading of neasted models with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Any idea why the following code is working proprely, returns the device with sensors and measuraments

```
public function getLastMinutes($device_id,$sensor_id,$minutes = 10) {
...
        $devices = Auth::user()->devices()->where("device_id",$device_id)->with(array('sensors.measurements' => function($query) use ($minutes,$sensor_id) {
            $date = new DateTime;
            $date->modify(-1*$minutes.' minutes');
            $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $query->where('measurements.created_at','>=',$formatted_date);

        }))->get()->toArray();
        return Response::json($devices);
...
```

but when i add the second **where("sensor_id",$sensor_id)** the measuraments disappiers from the json object returned

```
public function getLastMinutes($device_id,$sensor_id,$minutes = 10) {
...
        $devices = Auth::user()->devices()->where("device_id",$device_id)->with(array('sensors.measurements' => function($query) use ($minutes,$sensor_id) {
            $date = new DateTime;
            $date->modify(-1*$minutes.' minutes');
            $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $query->where("sensor_id",$sensor_id)->where('measurements.created_at','>=',$formatted_date);

        }))->get()->toArray();
        return Response::json($devices);
...
```

There is something i'm missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: where is `$sensor_id` defined?

Comment: i've updated the code so it's more clear, anyway $sensor_id is well defined no problem, infact in both cases the sensor object is returned

Comment: I would recommend install the https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the problem. by doing `with(array('sensors.measurements ....` in the object query you do not have any access to sensor... this means that by doing this `$query->where("sensor_id",$sensor_id)` the sensors_id will be searched on the measurements table... which is uncorrected. So the solution is have to with one that contains `'sensors'` and another one that contains `'sensors.measuraments'`.

So from this (wrong)

```
    public function getLastMinutes($device_id,$sensor_id,$minutes = 10) {
...
        $devices = Auth::user()->devices()->where("device_id",$device_id)->with(array('sensors.measurements' => function($query) use ($minutes,$sensor_id) {
            $date = new DateTime;
            $date->modify(-1*$minutes.' minutes');
            $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $query->where("sensor_id",$sensor_id)->where('measurements.created_at','>=',$formatted_date);

        }))->get()->toArray();
        return Response::json($devices);
...
```

to this one (correct)

```
...
$devices = Auth::user()->devices()->where("device_id",$device_id)
            ->with(array('sensors' => function($query) use ($sensor_id) {
                $query->where('sensors.sensor_id',$sensor_id);
            }))
            ->with(array('sensors.measurements' => function($query) use ($minutes,$sensor_id) {
                $date = new DateTime;
                $date->modify(-1*$minutes.' minutes');
                $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $query->where('measurements.created_at','>=',$formatted_date);
            }))
            ->get()->toArray();
            return Response::json($devices);
...
```

little tip. laravel-debugbar is a great project and you should check it out, but it actually did not help me much since i have a SPA and Laravel is doing a RESTFUL json server and for some reason laravel-debugbar did not kick in... but this little piece of code was atually great (taken from [Get the query executed in Laravel 3/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4))

```
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        $last_query = end($queries);
        return Response::json($last_query);
```

Hope can help you