# Multiple relationships on same table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

In my Property Model I have these two relationships defined

```
public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany('Image')
        ->where('approved', '=', 1);
}
public function pending_images() {
    return $this->hasMany('Image')
        ->where('approved', '=', 0);
}
```

In my Controller, I create a Property object and try to fetch both the approved and pending images.

```
$images = $property->images;
$pending = $property->pending_images;

var_dump($images);
var_dump($pending);
exit;
```

The `$images` variable is a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` as expected.

However, `$pending` is just `NULL`!

I try fetching the last DB query, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14536215/704803), and it seems that the pending query is not even being executed. (The last query run has `approved = 1`, which is for the `images` relationship.)

My suspicion is that it might be a problem that the relationship is on the same table but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename that relation to camelCase:

```
public function pendingImages() {
   return $this->hasMany('Image')
     ->where('approved', '=', 0);
}
```

Then it will work as expected, moreover you will be able to access it either way:

```
$property->pending_images == $property->pendingImages;
```

Dynamic properties work only with camelCased methods, that's all.