# How to enable the query logs in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, logging, laravel-5

I have been searching from a while how can I log the sql queries executed in 
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"

But everything I found is about the version 4 , have not found any working solution for 5.0 like these:
    [Get the query executed in Laravel 3/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536165/get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-3-4) and 
    [How to get the query executed in Laravel 5 ? DB::getQueryLog returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr) and
        http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/log-db-queries

Some are describe how to use it in laravel 5 but it doesn't seems to be working for me. I just want to write the sql logs in file. That's all, can any one tell me how can I do it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you enabled `DB::enableQueryLog();` ?

Comment: I have followed this one also. http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/query-logging-in-laravel-5/

Comment: I have created a middle ware for DB::enableQueryLog();

Comment: If you are using ubuntu, have you given the write permission to your log file ?

Comment: Yes permission  are already 777 to the entire directory.

Comment: Can you able to retrieve the query after the middleware ?

Comment: I think i found the solution it was just about that middle ware should load with application starts like this https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style

Comment: Yes ofcourse, this [image](http://stackphp.com/img/onion.png) explains a lot :) and i referred initially .. You able to retrieve query after the middleware ?

Comment: You're welcome, I have posted an answer for the future readers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable `DB::enableQueryLog();` and you should able to get the query after your middle ware.

Here is the image which explains soundly[image]

Thanks to [Mattstauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style)